# Join http results

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular7

I need to join the results of this two http requests:

`this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");`
`this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");`

by his columns `todo.userId = user.id`

Which is the best way to accomplish this?

I'm using angular 7

I know this is a question asked in so many places, but I didn't found one that fits my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are literally trying to join all of the todo items up with their users by the user id, `Array.map` will do the job.

After you get both data sets, just use `Array.map` to cycle through all of the Users and grab their todos

```js
// This function is just to fake the `this.http.get`
function httpGet(url) {
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const data = await result.json();
    resolve(data);
  });
}

// Create an array of promises to resolve your endpoints at once

const promises = [
  httpGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'),
  httpGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
];

// Wait for both promises to finish, then use Array.map to 'join' them
Promise.all(promises).then( results => {
  const todos = results[0];
  const users = results[1];


  // This is the notable part
  const result = users.map( u => {
    u.todos = todos.filter( t => t.userId === u.id );
    return u;
  });
  // End of notable part

  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but I have noticed a tendency to -1 answers to extremely lazy _questions_ presumably in an effort to encourage askers to put in some effort? That said, +1 for an actual answer.

Comment: tank you very much @mwilson! that is exactly what I was searching!

Comment: I think @msanford is probably correct; you are being downvoted for choosing to answer what some may perceive as a poorly worded question. That said...have an upvote.

Answer (score -2):

You can use rxJs method `forkJoin`.

```
forkJoin(
   this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"),
   this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
)
.subscribe(result => { 
   // make your stuff here.
   console.log(result)
 });
```

You also can pass as object

```
forkJoin({
   todos: this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"); 
   users: this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
})
.subscribe(result => { 
   // make your stuff here.
   const allObjects = {
      result.todos,
      result.users
   }
 });
```

Comment: the two results can only be joined manually? There's no functions for that?, Like combineLatest, map, merge or something like that?

Comment: This isn't joining anything. All this does is put two responses into an object (similar functionality to something like `Promise.all`). I think the OP wants to literally merge / join the both data sets into one.

Comment: The 'correct' answer is the same, but mapping ```result.todos``` and ```result.users```. I know that difficulties arise, but you must have the ability to think

Comment: I don't see how the correct answer and this answer are the same. The question was how to join two datasets into one. You don't address that at all. I think you misunderstood the question.